# tomcat/struts startup throwing ClassNotFoundException for java.io.File

Tags: tomcat, struts2, classloader

I've run into a strange problem.  When I start up tomcat with my webapp (struts 2) I see this in catalina.out.  It's looking for java.io.File in my app's classes directory, and of course can't find it.  It's also looking for a number of other core java classes like Comparator.

Does anyone know why it's looking there?  In the stacktrace I see opensymphony which implies it's a Struts problem, and one guess is that it's a configuration problem involving classloaders, but I'm still confused.

I replaced the path with "" in the stack trace below.

```
    12:50:12.547 [main] DEBUG c.o.x.u.c.FileResourceStore - Unable to read file [java/io/File.class]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/<company name>/WEB-INF/classes/java/io/File.class (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.classloader.FileResourceStore.read(FileResourceStore.java:33) ~[xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.classloader.ResourceStoreClassLoader.fastFindClass(ResourceStoreClassLoader.java:31) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.classloader.ResourceStoreClassLoader.loadClass(ResourceStoreClassLoader.java:45) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more info. Could you post your struts.xml or (if there is one) your struts.properties?
Moreover be aware that you are running an old version of S2 and if I recall correctly it changed something in some of the class you posted.

Comment: well i am agree first let us know which version you are using